# Определение запоздалого ответа

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

На сайте присутствует очередь запоздалых ответов. Сколько времени с момента публикации вопроса должно пройти, чтобы новый ответ считался запоздалым и попал в эту очередь?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222413/339911) на MSE сообщение попадает в очередь проверки "запоздалые ответы" при одновременном выполнении двух условий:

- Ответ опубликован как минимум через 30 дней после задания вопроса;
- Ответ опубликован участником с репутацией не более 50.

При этом по ссылке на MSE приведена интересная ситуация, что в очередь проверки запоздалых ответов сам ответ попал с задержкой более двух лет. Это случилось по причине того, что на момент публикации ответа у отвечающего было достаточно репутации, чтобы ответ не попал в очередь, а через пару лет репутация упала ниже порога. После этого алгоритм выбора сообщений для очереди запоздалых ответов выбрал этот ответ как подходящий. Получается, сообщение может (ну, или раньше могло, по крайней мере) попасть в очередь совсем не в тот же день, когда было опубликовано.

Comment: *без учёта бонуса за ассоциацию учётных записей* — насколько вижу, как раз «с учётом». за несколько лет ни разу не встречал в очереди ни одного ответа от участника с репутацией выше 49 (на тот момент, когда движок принимает решение — добавлять ли в очередь данный ответ).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin убрал эту часть, там речь всё же о блокировке учётной записи, а не о бонусе за ассоциацию. Перевод дал сбой.

Comment: 1. *Получается, сообщение может (ну, или раньше могло, по крайней мере) попасть в очередь совсем не в тот же день, когда было опубликовано.* — и сейчас попадает. недели две-три назад в очередь попал ответ, данный несколько месяцев назад. тот, кто его дал, «спустил» всю репутацию на конкурс, её осталось меньше 50. кстати, про точное количество: 2. *с репутацией не более 50* — всё-таки «не более 49». при репутации ровно 50 ответ не попадает в очередь проверок. в [изначальном вопросе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/298597), не оговаривается граничный случай. граница как раз между 49 и 50

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в том сообщении, на которое я ссылаюсь, сказано «50 or less»

Comment: да, так и сказано. а в подтверждение слов ссылается автор сообщения на [другое сообщение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/298597), в котором граничное условие не упомянуто. впрочем, даже если и было бы упомянуто (например, «50 или меньше»), это не соответствовало бы наблюдаемой (мною) реальности: «49 или меньше». // нет, я не предлагаю вам ещё раз править ответ. пусть остаётся как есть. тот, кому действительно интересна реальная граница, увидит это и из комментариев.